# Доступ к ftp через домен сайта или через filezilla

Tags: hosting, ftp-сервер, filezilla, http-status-code-403

У меня есть такая информация
FTP:
логин: ***

пароль: ***

сервер: sitename

Сайт, где мне нужно работать: sitename/myname

Захожу по этой ссылке sitename/myname и получаю: 403 forbidden you don't access /myname/ on this server..

Скачала FileZilla,
запустила, тоже не работает.

Как мне получить доступ? Правильно я делаю?

Comment: Подробнее информацию пожалуйста. У меня тоже вечная проблема, тыкаю по `sftp` и мой ip адрес уже в блокировке. Даже по `ftp` уже не пускают. Приходиться дзынькать в поддержку чтобы разблокировали. Говорят что на `ssh` ещё не дорос.

Comment: Мне создали поддомен и дали ссылку на сайт, где мне предстоит работать + логин и пароль. Если я зайду по этой ссылке сервер/моеимя то должна выводиться страница авторизации или сам сайт? У меня выходит ошибка 403.

Comment: Сначала скажите: в FileZilla вы вошли? Чтобы исправить разрешения нужен доступ по **ftp**.